# Show that $(V/U)/(W/U)\cong V/W$

Tags: linear-algebra

$K$ is a field,$V$ is a $K$-vectorspace and $U\subseteq W\subseteq V$.

I know that I have to show that the left and the right side are both vectorspaces which bases with same dimensions. But I don't know how do to that.

Support would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "I know that I have to show that [...] which bases with same dimensions" Not necessarily. Just demonstrating the existence of an isomorphism is enough. And once you get to grips with what the elements of each vector space look like, the answer might be obvious.

Comment: Let $\phi:V/U \to V/W$ be the function $\phi(v+U) = v+W$. So that is a well defined correspondence, surjective and linear... whats $ker\phi$?(I guess $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$)

Comment: @dem0nakos can you please explain why this map is well defined i.e if $v+U=z+U$ then $v+W=z+W$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $f:\frac{V/U}{W/U} \rightarrow V/W$ defined by $f((v+U)+W/U)=v+W$. Note that $(v+U)+W/U$ is a coset in $V/U$. The verification that this is indeed an isomorphism is left as an exercise.

This result is known as the third isomorphism theorem.

Claim: $f$ is an isomorphism.

$f((v+U)+W/U+(v'+U)+W/U)=v+W+v'+W=(v+v')+W=f(((v+v')+U)+W/U)$. Hence, $f$ is a homomorphism. Also, $f$ is clearly bijective. Hence, $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Can you please give me the solution?